# How to have multiple where clause in dexie query on same property?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have a array of strings and it is indexed in dexie.
I need to write a query that searches for the rows that don't have a string(a) and has a string(b).
I can do it with 1st condition, but for second condition, I can't apply where clause after *notEqual* as it returns *collection* and where can be applied only on *table* object

```
db.table.where('array').notEqual('String(a)').toArray()
```

Is it possible to apply second where clause, or is there any other approach to achieve the goal?

EDIT:
Other possible solutions, not with multiple where clauses.

```
db.table.toCollection(function (e) { 
  return (!e.array.includes('String(a)') && e.array.includes('String(b)')) 
}).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like

```
db.table.where('key1').notEqual('String(a)').and('key2').notEqual('String(b)').toArray()
```

Comment: notEqual is not a function of ...and. Also filter function should be given as argument for and.

Comment: notEqual() is a WhereClause method, so this will not work because and() returns a Collection, not a WhereClause object.